# Calculate average (AVG) including missing data in a date range in Redshift DB

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Consider I have the following set of data

```
   s_date   | sales 
------------+-------
 2020-08-04 |    10
 2020-08-05 |    20
 2020-08-07 |    10
 2020-08-08 |    20
 2020-08-09 |    10
 2020-08-10 |    30
 2020-08-11 |    20
 2020-08-12 |    10
```

I want to calculate the average for 'Sales' for each week. Please note that the data is missing for the date 2020-08-03 and 2020-08-06 for week starting on 2020-08-03.

When I am calculating weekly average using the **AVG()** function, it calculates the average based on the available records.

Following is the query that I am trying and the response that I am getting from it.

```
select trunc(date_trunc('WEEK', s_date)::timestamp) as week, avg(sales) 
from test_temp.sales group by week;
```

Result:

```
    week    | avg 
------------+-----
 2020-08-03 |  14
 2020-08-10 |  20
```

**However I want to calculate the average considering 0 as the value for missing dates**. So the average calculation should be done with the following values.

```
   s_date   | sales 
------------+-------
 2020-08-03 |     0
 2020-08-04 |    10
 2020-08-05 |    20
 2020-08-06 |     0
 2020-08-07 |    10
 2020-08-08 |    20
 2020-08-09 |    10
 2020-08-10 |    30
 2020-08-11 |    20
 2020-08-12 |    10
```

Expected Result:

```
    week    | avg 
------------+-----
 2020-08-03 |  10 // Expected value
 2020-08-10 |  20
```

Can anyone please let me know how to can we calculate the average as expected?

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Take the sum and divide by 7:

```
select trunc(date_trunc('WEEK', s_date)::timestamp) as week, sum(sales) / 7
from test_temp.sales
group by week;
```

EDIT:

To handle the last week, you can do something like this:

```
select trunc(date_trunc('WEEK', s_date)::timestamp) as week,
       sum(sales) / least(7, current_date - trunc(date_trunc('WEEK', s_date)::timestamp))
from test_temp.sales
group by week;
```

Comment: Can we enhance it in some way so that it takes care of the available day in the last week? For example if we are running this on Tuesday, the last week will contain only 2 days, so I want the division of sum by 2.
Also could there be a way to re-use this for monthly avg calculation? In case of monthly avg calculation the no of days in a month varies based on month (30 or 31 days) and year (Feb, 28 or 29 days).